# DJango: formatting json serialization

Tags: python, django, json

I have the following DJango view

```
def company(request):
    company_list = Company.objects.all()
    output = serializers.serialize('json', company_list, fields=('name','phonenumber','email','companylogo'))
    return HttpResponse(output, content_type="application/json")
```

it result as follows:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "test.company", "fields": {"companylogo": null, "phonenumber": "741.999.5554", "name": "Remax", "email": "home@remax.co.il"}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "test.company", "fields": {"companylogo": null, "phonenumber": "641-7778889", "name": "remixa", "email": "a@aa.com"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "test.company", "fields": {"companylogo": null, "phonenumber": "658-2233444", "name": "remix", "email": "b@bbb.com"}}, {"pk": 7, "model": "test.company", "fields": {"companylogo": null, "phonenumber": "996-7778880", "name": "remix", "email": "a@aba.com"}}]
```

my questions:
1. can i control the order of the fields
2. can i change the name of the fields
3. I was expecting to see the result with indentation in the browser i.e. instead of one long line to see something like this:

```
[
  {
     "pk": 1, 
     "model": "test.company", 
     "fields": 
     {
         "companylogo": null, 
         "phonenumber": "741.999.5554", 
         "name": "Remax", 
         "email": "home@remax.co.il"
     }
  }, 
  {
     "pk": 4, 
     "model": "test.company", 
     "fields": 
     {
        "companylogo": null,  
        "phonenumber": "641-7778889", 
        "name": "remixa", 
        "email": "a@aa.com"
     }
  }, 
  ....
 }
```

]

Answer (score 32):

you can get pretty format in this way:

```
return JsonResponse(your_json_dict, json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})
```

[django doc as the first comment say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

Comment: As JsonResponse is the way to go in later versions of Django (1.7 i think), i would say that this answer is the one to go with.

Comment: This is the way to go as of 2014 (and today 2018)

Answer (score 7):

Python (unrelated to Django and starting with 2.6) has a built in [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library that can accomplish the indentation you require.  If you are looking for something quick and dirty for debug purposes you could do something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers
import json


def company(request, pretty=False):
    company_list = Company.objects.all()
    output = serializers.serialize('json', company_list, fields=('name','phonenumber','email','companylogo'))
    if pretty:
        output = json.dumps(json.loads(output), indent=4))
    return HttpResponse(output, content_type="application/json")
```

But this is a performance issue if the `Company` model is large.  I recommend taking Dan R's advice and use a browser plugin to parse and render the json or come up with some other client side solution.  I have a script that takes in a json file and does exactly the same thing as the code above, reads in the json and prints it out with `indent=4`.

As for sorting your output, you can just use the [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) method on your query set:

```
def company(request):
    company_list = Company.objects.order_by("sorting_field")
    ...
```

And if you always want that model sorted that way, you can use the [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#ordering) meta-class option:

```
class Company(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["sorting_field"]
    ...
```

As a final note, If your intent is to expose your models with a web service, I highly recommend taking a look at [tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  It may help you in the long run as it provides many other convenient features that help towards that end.

Answer (score 2):

With Django 1.7 I can get nicely indented JSON by using the `indent` parameter of the serializer. For instance, in a command that dumps data from my database:

```
self.stdout.write(serializers.serialize("json",
                                        records,
                                        indent=2))
```

The `indent` parameter has been in Django since version 1.5. The output I get looks like this:

```
[
{ 
  "fields": {
    "type": "something",
    "word": "something else",
  },
  "model": "whatever",
  "pk": 887060
},
{ 
  "fields": {
    "type": "something more",
    "word": "and another thing",
  },
  "model": "whatever",
  "pk": 887061
},
...
```

To order your *records* then you'd have to do what [Kevin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149380/1906307) and use `order_by`, or whatever method you want to order the records you pass to the serializer. For instance, I use `itertools.chain` to order different querysets that return instances of different models.

The serializer does not support ordering *fields* according to your preferences, or renaming them. You have to write your own code to do this or use an external tool.

Comment: It would be nice having this also in the [Django documentation about serializing objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/), but as of now it's just used in an example without explanation.

Answer (score -3):

JSON doesn't have indentation, it's simply structured data. Browsers or other tools may format the JSON so that it looks nice but by default it's not there. It's also not part of the JSON as the formatting is just how it looks on the screen. JSON is often processed by other code or services so they don't care about indentation, as long as the data is structured correctly.

Comment: mine is also just a service where the looking nice seems like not important but it is for debug purposes

Comment: If you just want it to look nice when viewing it in your browser search for a JSON Viewer plugin in your browsers extension/plugin site.