# Django Json Response formatting in templates

Tags: json, django, django-templates

is it somehow possible to keep the JSON response as it is as well as indent it as a proper format?

I want to render the list_text in my list.html template, but the json response comes up different everytime. Is it possible to keep it fixed and properly indented?

```
obj = {
                list_text[0],
                list_text[1],
                list_text[2],
                list_text[3],
                list_text[4],
                list_text[5],
                list_text[6],
                list_text[7],
            }
            return render(request, 'card/list.html', {'form':form, 'list_text': obj})
```

I found a similar JSON article here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109918/django-formatting-json-serialization)

But it is for JSON Serialization or something like that I am looking to pass it on to the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the order to be maintained use a list instead of a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

```
obj = [
    list_text[0],
    list_text[1],
    list_text[2],
    list_text[3],
    list_text[4],
    list_text[5],
    list_text[6],
    list_text[7],
]
return render(request, 'card/list.html', {'form':form, 'list_text': obj})
```

You can probably pass `list_text` as it looks like it is a list.

Now in order to get proper indentation in your template the simplest approach is to convert your Python objects to a JSON string.

```
list_text_as_a_string = json.dumps(obj, indent=2)
return render(request, 'card/list.html', {'form':form, 'list_text': list_text_as_a_string})
```

Note the `indent=2`. By default [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) avoids any extra white space.

Now in your template simple do

```
<pre>{{ list_text }}</pre>
```

The [pre tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) takes preformatted text and renders it as it is. (Normally HTML ignore extra white space). It also uses a fixed width font so things look better.